# vbscript, recursively set object

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm trying to make a script to upload my personal pictures to Flickr through sending mail.  The full script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/6pQFMZmk

I have chosen to use Excel as a database to remember what's been uploaded before; for every file I need to search in the spreadsheet if it has been uploaded already. This is done by setting a variable `objCell` to the result of the `find` function.
This works the first time around, but the second time I set the `objCell` I get the error: `runtime error: Object variable not set`

The relevant part of the code is the following:

```
    Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)  
        For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        wscript.echo "VOLGENDE FOLDER"
        wscript.echo ""

        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            if soort.Exists(UCase(Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name,".") + 1))) Then 
                strSearchTerm = objFile.Name & objFile.Size & objFile.DateLastModified

                msgbox strSearchTerm & " ;   " & objCell & " ;   " & xlFormulas & " ;   " & xlPart & " ;   " & xlByRows & " ;   " & xlNext & " ;   " & boolMatchCase
                'THE LINE UNDER HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                Set objCell = objWorkSheet.Cells.Find(strSearchTerm, objCell, xlFormulas,xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, boolMatchCase)

                If Not objCell Is Nothing Then 
                    'I found it!, don't upload...
                    objCell = Nothing
                Else
                    'not fout; upload
                    temp = upload(subfolder.path & "\" & objFile.Name)
                    wscript.echo String(6-len(introw)," ") & intRow & " " & Subfolder.Path & " " & objFile.Name & " ;   " & Mid(Subfolder.Path, InStrRev(Subfolder.Path, "\")+1) & " ;   " &  UCase(Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name,".") + 1)) & " " & objFile.Size
                    if temp then
                        objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value =  strSearchTerm
                        objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).value = Now()
                    Else
                        objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value =  objFile.Name
                        objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).value = "upload failed"
                    End if
                    intRow = intRow + 1
                End if
            Else
                wscript.echo objFile.name & ": " & Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name,".") + 1) & " is niet in type"
            End if
        Next
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
  End Sub
```

I do realize I could use a simple text file to keep track of uploads; but I've set my mind on using excel; later-on I do plan on expanding the script and for this Excel would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Set` to assign an object (Nothing is an object!) to a variable:

```
objCell = Nothing
```

==>

```
Set objCell = Nothing
```

Comment: aaaah, that's so logical. Will try tonight